# Android library vs. external jar

Tags: android

I have an external jar that I can use in my Android application, I just reference it as an external jar from my application. Is there any benefit in creating an Android library project with this external jar for Android applications to use, or is this pretty much the same as referencing the external jar?

Comment: I didn't get this yet. so what is the difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off using the jar as it is in your android project. The android library project makes sense **only when you are developing common code from scratch**. That way instead of making a jar first and then including it in a project, you can create an android library project and then refer it in other projects.

Other than that I can't seem to find real good reasons for it.

Anybody, can you think of any?

Answer (score 2):

Making a library project makes sense only in one case: if you want to share some application resources across all the apps (for example layouts, drawables, strings etc). If you just need some common java code there is no any difference between external jar and library project.

Comment: Is there any optimization difference? Eg. removing unused classes in building APK.